# Firebird second instance is not accessible

Tags: database, firebird, firebird2.5, isql

My requirement is to create a named instance, while there is a default instance running on the same machine and connect to it, through some kind of management console or command line.

I created a firebird 2.5 second instance using

```
instsvc install -auto -superserver -guardian -name secondservice
instsvc start -name secondservice
```

This created the engine service and guardian service and was confirmed running using firebird control centre and through services window.

However I am unable to connect to the instance using ibo console when I put the parameters to host name as localhost/secondservice, nor can I cannot to it through isql using

```
isql localhost\secondservice:employee
```

I downloaded the zip file through 
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/firebird/firebird-win32/2.5.4-Release/Firebird-2.5.4.26856-0_Win32.zip

Would anyone have any idea what is missing?

Comment: Those FB instances must listen to different port - did you change the port of the `secondservice` in the firebird.conf file? If you did then you have to use that port in your connection string too.

Comment: I changed the port in the firebird.conf above the bin directory. However running netstat I couldnt confirm it was running on another port. Service was up with a different name. I am trying to connect through isql so connection strings I havent checked yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have a concept of named instances like SQL Server. If you want to run a second instance, then the `firebird.conf` file of that instance must have a different value for the configuration option `RemoteServicePort` (which defaults to 3050), and you need to specify that port number when connecting (say you configured the port on `13050`):

```
isql localhost/13050:employee
```

Running multiple instances of the server, also requires you to have separate installations for each instance.

Comment: starting with firebird 2.1 you can http://www.destructor.de/firebird/multiinstance.htm

But neither port or name has not worked for me. I am able to connect to the first instance without trouble.

Comment: http://firebird-tips.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/firebird-21-manual-installation.html installation steps were followed to install the second instance(second service)

Comment: @user3614386  Its not enough to start the second instance with a different port, you have to connect to it using that port too.  It all works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks invalid config ref through registry messed it up. Thank you. I put what i did in the question just incase it would help anyone

Answer (score 2):

This worked

I made sure

1. Registry does not have any firebird related keys that are pointing to firebird 1.5 or anything else.
2. echo %FIREBIRD% does not print a value
3. firebird.conf has below two lines (only line changed was the port from 3050 to 3070):

   ```
   #RemoteServiceName = gds_db
   RemoteServicePort = 3070
   ```

Ran

```
instsvc stop -name secondservice

instsvc stop -name DefaultInstance

instsvc r -n secondservice

instsvc install -auto -superserver -guardian -name secondservice

instsvc start -name secondservice
```

Services are up and running

telnet -a confirms service is listening on 3070 port.

```
isql localhost/3070:C:\test.fdb -user SYSDBA -pass masterkey
```

worked for me

What sorted it was clearing out ENV variables and registry, nothing much to it after that.

Comment: About point three: lines starting with `#` are comments so effectively it's value is not important, the default will be used.